# PHP: Find the most frequent word(s) appeared in a String or Array

Tags: php, string, function

I know I can use this way to find the most frequent element in an array:

*(correct me if I am wrong)*

```
$array = array('good', 'good', 'good', 'cool');     
$array = array_count_values($array);
$array = array_keys($array);
$element = $array[0]
```

How about if I want to find the most frequent word(s) instead of the most frequent element:

*(In this case it would be the words `apple` and `me`)*

```
$array = array('apple bb','cc apple','d','ccc ab','apple ccccc','cc cccc me me me')
```

---

If I convert the array into a string using `implode` first,

How can I find it/them in the simplest way?

And what are the other methods I can use to find it/them without `implode` then `explode`?

Comment: what's the problem with using implode? :o, I think it's a good enough solution

Comment: @NiftyDude I fancy a shorter and simpler solution if there's one:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) works on a string, which means you only need to implode, not to explode again: and using a second argument of 1 will count the occurrences of each word. It's biggest advantage is that it takes punctuation marks into account when splitting the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is this, as you mentioned `implode()` and `explode()`

```
$array = array('apple bb','cc apple','d','ccc ab','apple ccccc','cc cccc');
$array2 = array_count_values(explode(' ', implode(' ', $array)));
echo key($array2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about the second segment of your question, for the first, here's a function I found on [WebDeveloper](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?59820-Find-the-most-common-value-in-an-array&p=335027#post335027)

```
function array_most_common($input) 
{ 
  $counted = array_count_values($input); 
  arsort($counted); 
  return(key($counted));     
}
```

Comment: This works just fine. I use it to get the most common emoji out of an array of emojis.

Answer (score 3):

One working way to find most frequent/repeated word(s) in a string or in an array. using PHP

In a String,

```
<?php

$str = "hi its me . hi its me .hello its me hi";

$array = explode(" ",$str);

$array = array_count_values($array);

arsort($array);

$highest = current($array);

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    if($value == $highest)
        $repeat[] = $key;
?>
```

here `$repeat[]` contains most repeated word(s) in the string.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
<?php

function getMostFrequentInArray($array)
{

   // e.g. $array = array('apple bb','cc apple','d','ccc ab','apple ccccc','cc cccc');

   $token_array = array();

   for ($array as $item)
   {
        $token_array[] = explode(" ",$item);
   }

   $array_by_frequency = array_count_values($token_array);
   $element = $array_by_frequency[0];

   return $element;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function highfreqwords($arr){
    $counts = array_count_values(str_word_count(implode(" ",$arr),1));
    arsort($counts);
    return $counts;
}
```

Algorithm

- Implode your array of sentences to make one long sentence.
- use `str_word_count(array,1)` to return all the words in that big sentence.
- use `array_count_values(array)` to count all the values
- use `arsort()` to short associative array in descending order